# React.js versioned documentation recommendation

Tags: reactjs, dropdown, documentation, versioning

I have a React web application that displays documentation for an application that works on both Android and iOS. However, I want to organize this documentation into versions. My plan is to create a separate component for each version, and users can choose a version from a dropdown list. Here's my current folder structure:

```
docs
-android.jsx
-ios.jsx
-android
--v_0_0_0.jsx
-ios
--v_0_0_0.jsx
```

The issue I'm facing is that I'll have to import each version separately into the main Android and iOS pages and implement them using conditional if-else structures. How can I make this process more efficient?